# PlotlyJS unix timestamp xaxis

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

If i have a unix timestamp as my xaxis, how can i format the xaxis ticks so that they are human readable. Example:

```
var x = [
    1599149438,
1599152204,
1599159972,
1599162392,
1599163074,
1598638057,
1598638162,
1598638226,
1598638737,
1598886967,
1598887053,
1598887100,
1598888440,
1598888461,
1598890461,
1598891566,
1598968484,
1598968486,
1598968890,
1598969703,
1598973067,
1598991253,
1599071690,
1599071701,
1599136836,
1599137112,
1599137318,
1599137466,
1599137670,
1599150700,
1599155337,
1599155392,
1599155577,
1599235215,
1599235282,
1598976507,
1598991992,
1598992284,
1598992486,
1599064430,
1599064971,
1599066545,
1599069206,
1599069328,
1599069429,
1599071321,
1599137701,
1599139341,
1599139739,
1599139742,
1599143693,
1599144879,
1599150125,
1599155492,
1599156034,
1599162164,
1599163112,
1598634550,
1598634555,
1598637859,
1598637942,
1598638040,
1598638649,
1598639958,
1598640067,
1598640069,
1598640159,
1598640245,
1598640257,
1598640954,
1598641170,
1598649524,
1598649560,
1598884823,
1598885218,
1598885439,
1598887053,
1598887054,
1598890406,
1598890465,
1598892329,
1598899069,
1598903026,
1598903207,
1598903209,
1598903305,
1598903454,
1598903458,
1598968859,
1598988950,
1599064427,
1599064600,
1599065298,
1599069186,
1599071503,
1599137132,
1599142552,
1599142554,
1599142600,
1599147475,
1599151206,
1599151209,
1599233072,
1599235214,
1599235215,
1598637923,
1598879892,
1598885127,
1598888004,
1598890401,
1598890430,
1598891168,
1598891349,
1598891858,
1598892218,
1598897872,
1598899068,
1598899198,
1598903025,
1598967466,
1598969602,
1598970350,
1598970387,
1598970504,
1598973061,
1598978899,
1598978899,
1598989060,
1598989167,
1598990662,
1598990667,
1598992523,
1599057106,
1599059031,
1599064597,
1599064854,
1599065090,
1599066202,
1599066909,
1599077441,
1599137013,
1599142759,
1599142939,
1599143690,
1599144683,
1599144913,
1599147476,
1599150607,
1599150699,
1599155252,
1599234372,
1599234511,
1599234706,
1599234781,
1599235177,
1598989250,
1598889205,
1599066930,
1599067016,
1598885039,
1598885441,
1598888004,
1598888004,
1598970289,
1599139727,
1599142955,
1599155702,
1599155836,
1599156105,
1599156105,
1599233225,
1599233226,
1599234812,
1599234912,
1598638124,
1598638194,
1598886968,
1598886972,
1598989172,
1599155569,
1598888562,
1598889225,
1598991163,
1599057240,
1599065194,
1599066319,
1599066405,
1599066542,
1599066887,
1599071301,
1599071757,
1599071776,
1599072050,
1599136844,
1599142567,
1599149442,
1599155431,
1599232940,
1599233052,
1599233221,
1599233644,
1598638655,
1599071505,
1599235219,
1598970796,
1599150632,
1599137485,
1598884828,
1598984576,
1598984582,
1598984582,
1598984582,
1598984582,
1598984582,
1598984582,
1598984582,
1598984582,
1598984582,
1598984582,
1598984582,
1598984582,
1598984582,
1598984582,
1598984582,
1598984582,
1598984582,
1598984582,
1598984582,
1598984582,
1598984582,
1598984582,
1598984582,
1598984582,
1598984582,
1599155930

];
var y = [0.18, 0.38, 0.56, 0.46, 0.59, 0.4, 0.78, 0.77, 0.74, 0.42, 0.45, 0.39];
var data = [{
  x: x,
  y: y,
  type: 'histogram'
}];
var layout = {
  xaxis: {
    tickformat: "&H"  // For more formatting types, see: https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/master/README.md#locale_format
  }
}

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

https://codepen.io/maxfridbe/pen/JjXvbqe?editable=true%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fplotly.com%2Fjavascript%2Ftick-formatting%2F

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if PlotlyJS is able to do the conversion but you can use standard JS function to rewrite the timestamps:

```
var format = {year: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit'};
var data = [{
  x: x.map(unix => Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', format).format(unix*1000)),
  type: 'histogram'
}];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

`Intl.DateTimeFormat()` is my preferred way to do the conversion but
[Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript) lists a bunch of more options.

Additionaly, I removed your y data. Defining both x- and y-values only makes sense in combination with a histfunc.

Answer (score 1):

I iterated over the dataset and converted every timestamp in the array to JS date object with `new Date(timestamp)` and forwarded that array to `Plotly.newPlot()`. Standard Date object seems to be recognized by Plotly.